# Extended server_name (SNI Extension) not sent with jdk1.8.0 but send with jdk1.7.0

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, cxf, sni

I have implemented a JAX-WS client by using ApacheCXF (v3.0.4) and everything works successfully but the problem comes when I want to use a secure connection (SSL/TLS) with java 8 (jdk1.8.0_25).

I see the following exception in log (-Djavax.net.debug=all):

```
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description =    unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

After a depeer analysis I have observed the problem is caused because the with Java 8 the server_name (SNI) is not sent but with Java 7 it is sent and the web service invocation works successfully.

**Java 8 log (-Djavax.net.debug=all):** Missing "Extension server_name"

```
[...]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[...]
```

**Java 7 log (-Djavax.net.debug=all) (works):** "Extension server_name" is set

```
[...]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: testeo.hostname.es]
***
[...]
```

It is observed that with Java 7 the *Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: testeo.hostname.es]* is set and then the web service invocation works successfully.

Why didn't Java 8 set the server_name as Java 7 did? Is it a Java configuration issue?

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned, the cause is related to the JDK bug where using setHostnameVerifier() breaks SNI (Extension server_name).
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144566

Our workaround:
After testing we found that setting a connection's SSLSocketFactory to just about anything from the default seems to fix the issue.

This does not work:
`HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());`

This does work:
`HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactoryFacade());`

So, to fix it for a JAX-WS client, you could do something like this:
`bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", new SSLSocketFactoryFacade());`

Our SSLSocketFactory facade: (Note that it really doesn't do anything)

```
public class SSLSocketFactoryFacade extends SSLSocketFactory {

    SSLSocketFactory sslsf;

    public SSLSocketFactoryFacade() {
        sslsf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslsf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslsf.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String s, int i, boolean b) throws IOException {
        return sslsf.createSocket(socket, s, i, b);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslsf.createSocket(s, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inetAddress, int i1) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslsf.createSocket(s, i, inetAddress, i1);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inetAddress, int i) throws IOException {
        return createSocket(inetAddress, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inetAddress, int i, InetAddress inetAddress1, int i1) throws IOException {
        return createSocket(inetAddress, i, inetAddress1, i1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what's a bindingProvider and/or add code to demonstrate.  I would like to use your solution in trying to fix this bug in an existing system.

Comment: This facade class trick fixed my application in JDK8 along with the customized HostnameVerifier. Without a facade trick I was not able to use a custom verifier.

Comment: I had exception: "BuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" every time I restarted PC and started Tomcat with the client application. After restarting Tomcat everything worked. After looking into the logs I found out that for some reason the Extension server_name was not present in the ClientHello during first run. The  custom SSLSocketFactoryFacade fixed the issue. BTW Lombok's @Delegate annotation will make the class super small.

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem? if the facade doesn't do anything, is there something, that relies on the class name?

Answer (score 10):

Please use JDK version 8u141 and above where this issue has been fixed. Please review the  [JDK 8u141 Bugs Fixes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u141-bugfixes-3720387.html) page for more details

Answer (score 9):

You, or the underlying libs (the WS lib does it) might be using setHostnameVerifier(..)

There is a bug in java8, where if setHostnameVerifier(..) is used the SNI is not done from the client side.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072464

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution provided by Benjamin Parry, but it did not work for me.  After some digging around, I also found [this solution](http://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html) which looks very similar, however the SSLSocketFactoryFacade manually inserts the correct SSL header instead of being a pure pass-though.  Providing my final code below which is slightly different, but credit to be given to Girish Kamath at javabreaks for the basic idea:

```
    private static class SSLSocketFactoryFacade extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLSocketFactory sslsf;
    private SSLParameters sslParameters;

    public SSLSocketFactoryFacade(String hostName) {
        sslParameters = new SSLParameters();
        sslParameters.setServerNames(Arrays.asList(new SNIHostName(hostName)));
        sslsf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();;
    }

    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket();
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, InputStream arg1, boolean arg2) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        Socket socket = sslsf.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
        return socket;
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslsf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslsf.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }
}
```

And then I can call

```
sslConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactoryFacade(sslConnection.getURL().getHost()));
```

where `sslConnection` is the `HttpsURLConnection`.