# OkHttp with SNI: Connection reset on Java 7

Tags: java, java-7, okhttp, retrofit2, sni

The following snippet works perfectly as long as only one tls certificate is enabled on the nginx server.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("ENDPOINT").build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

Activating a site with a different certificate causes nginx to enable SNI. That apparently breaks both on Oracle Java 7 as well as OpenJDK 7.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:195)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:148)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
    at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Comment: If you enable Java's SSL debugging (via `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`), do you see the SNI (`server_name`) TLS extension being sent?  If not, this similar post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36343704/4072843.

Comment: @Castaglia Yes: `Extension server_name[...]`.
The error: `main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message`