# SSLHandshakeException in API 17 (JELLY_BEAN) when using custom CA

Tags: android, security, ssl, okhttp

I need connect to my server API with `TLS_v1`, server certificate signed by CA that not include in older version of android so i use this [Google's document](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) to implement custom `TrustManager`. Everything work on API 18 and above, but throw SSLHandshakeException in JELLY_BEAN(API 17):

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I have another server URL and certificate (in this case self-signed) that works even in JELLY_BEAN with same TrustManager implementation !!

I'm using OkHttp 2.4 for `HTTPS` client. I'm confusing what's goes wrong ?

Updated:
this is result of [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) :

[image]

intermediate and root TurkTrust CA (shown in above) was added to my `TrustManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible explanation is that the server requires [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to send the proper certificate back and sends only some default certificate if SNI is not used. Thus the client would not get the expected certificate and the validation would fail.

According to the documentation OkHTTP should support SNI, but [a recent report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480255/okhttp-with-sni-connection-reset-on-java-7) indicates otherwise. In the Changelog I cannot see when it was added. It might also be that support depends on the underlying libraries.

EDIT: based on the report from SSLLabs which was added to the question it is now clear that the problem is a missing intermediate certificate at the server. This is shown in the report by

```
Chain Issues: Incomplete, Extra Download, ....
```

In this case it will not help if the client has explicitly added the root CA (Türktrust Elektronik Sertifika...), because due to the missing intermediate CA (Türktrust SSL Sertifikasi Hizmitleri) no trust chain can be build from the leaf certificate of the site to the root certificate. From the report can also be seen that the server not only fails to include the chain certificate but that the server also adds some certificate which does not belong to the chain at all. Thus my guess is that there was an attempt to include a chain certificate but the wrong one was used and apart from that at the wrong place (after the root instead of after the lead certificate).

While some desktop browsers work around such problem most mobile browsers will not work around this server side misconfiguration and also the SSL apis for python, PHP, Java,... will also fail. Therefore this is a  problem which need to be fixed at the server.

Comment: API url is connect to exactly one ip, so i think SNI is not my case.

Comment: @MojtabaAsg: have you checked with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)? They show if any problems are to expect with a variety of TLS clients. Typical causes for problems are also missing chain certificates, shown by SSLLabs as "chain issues" and "extra download". These are just guesses: for more help you better present the URL in question.

Comment: I can't share api url but answer updated with filtered result.

Comment: @MojtabaAsg: the shared information help. Answer updated.

Comment: Vert thanks. I check with server admin as soon as possible . i hope this fix problem but how this case work in above jellybean ?

Comment: @MojtabaAsg: I think this should fix the problem for jellybean too because as far as I can guess from your information the cause is the same.

Comment: I mean if cause is server side why application work in kitkat,lolipop,marshmallow ?

Comment: @MojtabaAsg: I agree that this is really strange but I cannot tell from the information provided what's really going on there. Maybe it will help if you provide the code of what you actually did (i.e. like what the content of your custom key store really is).

Comment: you save me :) you are exactly detect problem