# All trusting HostnameVerifier causes SSL errors with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpurlconnection

I'm using HttpURLConnection to connect to SSL sites. Occasionally these use self signed certificates / otherwise badly behaved SSL so I have a mode where these an be accessed. I'm using the typical code recommended many places online:

```
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());


        // Don't verify host names
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

The problem is that this causes SSL errors for many sites, e.g.:

https://cong-shalom.org/
Causes:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

Output when javax.net.debug=all enabled:

```
    [java] Thread-8, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    [java] Thread-8, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
    [java] Thread-8, called closeSocket()
```

https://www.territrespicio.com
Causes:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Output when javax.net.debug=all enabled:

```
         [java] Thread-13, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
         [java] Thread-13, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
         [java] Thread-13, called closeSocket()
```

None of these issues are related to the TrustManager, commenting out the HostnameVerifier part always allows the connection to work correctly.

Notes:

- Java version: 1.8.0_111
- Unfortunately I can't switch to apache httpclient (there's a lot of code built around HttpURLConnection)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your issue is due to a bug in JDK [Custom HostnameVerifier disables SNI extension](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144566). You can also see in this thread [Extended server_name (SNI Extension) not sent with jdk1.8.0 but send with jdk1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817934/extended-server-name-sni-extension-not-sent-with-jdk1-8-0-but-send-with-jdk1-7)

From jdk 8u66, using a custom `HostnameVerifier` does not send `Extended server_name` extension during handshake. This bug will be fixed in version 8u152.

This is the trace of handshake invoking to `https://www.territrespicio.com` with your code

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1467981635 bytes = { 253, 197, 8, 192, 170, 180, 230, 6, 212, 233, 219, 201, 182, 39, 204, 176, 49, 215, 43, 41, 112, 204, 188, 29, 115, 235, 191, 74 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 233
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

This is the trace (working) removing

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

---

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1467981305 bytes = { 187, 36, 131, 239, 148, 148, 198, 107, 89, 74, 67, 33, 127, 76, 24, 17, 108, 254, 79, 104, 242, 239, 51, 36, 180, 244, 181, 45 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=www.territrespicio.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 264
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 89
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -2137263708 bytes = { 105, 47, 249, 171, 64, 55, 195, 235, 198, 159, 46, 193, 42, 65, 156, 243, 134, 177, 35, 221, 75, 16, 222, 103, 42, 55, 103, 231 }
Session ID:  {42, 151, 108, 66, 43, 195, 53, 201, 234, 24, 245, 14, 183, 242, 185, 128, 66, 115, 60, 35, 167, 159, 178, 238, 93, 155, 20, 195, 95, 155, 11, 79}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
***
```

You can see that adds in ClientHello the required extension

```
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=www.territrespicio.com]
```

There is no documented workaround. **So consider using a JDK version <8u66 or >=8u152**

### Updated -- Workaround

See the answer of @Dawuid in [SNI client-side mystery using Java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323704/sni-client-side-mystery-using-java8)

> **If you use a custom SSLSocketFactory without override createSocket()** (the method without parameters), the createSocket well parametrized is used and all works as expected (with client sni extension).

You can find a similar workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34296145/6371459). I have tried with just a wrapper and it works.

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
   new SSLSocketFactoryWrapper(sc.getSocketFactory()));
```

SSLSocketFactoryWrapper (full code)

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SSLSocketFactoryWrapper extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory factory;

    public   SSLSocketFactoryWrapper(SSLSocketFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    /* 
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return  factory.createSocket();
    }
    */

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {         
        return factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return factory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return factory.createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return factory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return factory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thannks pedrofb - I'm working my way towards testing this with 8u65 (my build environment causes delays). I had noticed that bug but dismissed it since I was on the latest jre (guess I should have noticed the fix hadn't been released!). Will update once tested. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again pedrofb! I had a lot of issues downgrading the JDK in my environment so I tried the workaround. It seems to work well in my initial testing. I'll be throwing a lot of SSL examples at it in the coming days to be sure, but it looks pretty certain that the workaround is the way to go (and if not, battling to downgrade the JDK should do it).