# Jsoup: ignore SSL errors

Tags: java, ssl, jsoup

I'm trying to download https://www.deviantart.com using Jsoup (v1.10.3), with `validateTLSCertificates(false)`. Java 8, UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 installed.

The exception thrown is `fatal, handshake_failure`. After setting `-Djavax.net.debug=all` we receive more details: `RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure`.

Also tried `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");` (suggested here [getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version while scraping data using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595021/getting-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-while)), and the "trust manager that does not validate certificate chains". It didn't help.

I can't believe in 2017 it's so hard for Java to download a simple URL. I just want a piece of code that downloads any given HTTPS URL while ignoring any SSL errors, without adding certificates to the trusted store or anything like that.

Thanks!

Full output for the SSL dump:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
pool-1-thread-1, setSoTimeout(20000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1489235422 bytes = { 95, 240, 147, 176, 192, 176, 220, 188, 41, 118, 230, 166, 80, 191, 204, 5, 32, 161, 184, 60, 42, 112, 96, 165, 83, 70, 37, 105 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 203
0000: 01 00 00 C7 03 03 59 C4   EE DE 5F F0 93 B0 C0 B0  ......Y..._.....
0010: DC BC 29 76 E6 A6 50 BF   CC 05 20 A1 B8 3C 2A 70  ..)v..P... ..<*p
0020: 60 A5 53 46 25 69 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  `.SF%i..d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 3A 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  :...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 16 00 14 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 02 03 02   01 02 02                 ...........
pool-1-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 203
[Raw write]: length = 208
0000: 16 03 03 00 CB 01 00 00   C7 03 03 59 C4 EE DE 5F  ...........Y..._
0010: F0 93 B0 C0 B0 DC BC 29   76 E6 A6 50 BF CC 05 20  .......)v..P... 
0020: A1 B8 3C 2A 70 60 A5 53   46 25 69 00 00 64 C0 24  ..<*p`.SF%i..d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 3A 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....:..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 16 00 14 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 02 03 02 01 02 02  ................
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
pool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
pool-1-thread-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
pool-1-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-1-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: The answers to #33595021 say repeatedly that `https.protocols` helps Java*7* not 8, and your problem is not in any way a cert trust problem, so those changes indeed are useless. Your problem is apparently failure to send SNI. JSoup's validateTLSCertificate(false) also changes hostname verification making this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692736/all-trusting-hostnameverifier-causes-ssl-errors-with-httpurlconnection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817934/extended-server-name-sni-extension-not-sent-with-jdk1-8-0-but-send-with-jdk1-7 and 8u141 reportedly fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. You are correct, I had an older JDK (although a current JRE, and this tripped me up). Upgrading the JDK to the latest current version fixed the issue. I thought I was going mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @dave_thompson_085 clarified everything, turns out it's a bug in Java 8 versions prior to 8u141, where it wouldn't send SNI.

Solution: make sure you have JRE/JDK >= 141.