# Java 11 JSOUP SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, jsoup

This my first post here so don't hesitate to tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm made a few line of code in `Java 11` to get information from a webstore with `JSOUP (1.14.2)`. Since the webstore as multiple page of data I'm using a loop to get all the url I want.

Here's a simplified exemple of what I'm doing :

```
for (int i = 1; i < 36; i++) {
    String url = ("https://www.play-in.com/rachat/hotlist/magic?p=" + i);

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Impossible de récuppérer les éléments de la page " + i + " : " + e);
    }

    //  here i'm parsing the HTML to return an array of object
}
```

When I run the programme I get :

```
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 2 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 3 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 4 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 5 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 6 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[...]
[main] INFO  ISmellProfits  - Number of result after HTML parsing : 24
```

And so on.
So the first `get()` is always a sucess and I can manipulate the result but then it seems to have an issued when calling multipe `Jsoup.connect()`.

Since I'm calling an `HTTPS` url my first thought was a certificate issue and I tried this solution [How to connect via HTTPS using Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744075/how-to-connect-via-https-using-jsoup) but it didn't helped. And if a `certificate` was really needed I shouldn't be able to have acces to the url the first time, but I might be wrong here since I don't know a lot on this domain.

Second thought was to use *parallel stream* :

```
List <String> links = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 36; i++) {
    String url = ("https://www.play-in.com/rachat/hotlist/magic?p=" + i);
    links.add(url);
}

links.parallelStream().forEach(link - > {
    Document doc = new Document("");
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();

        // here i'm parsing the HTML to return an array of object 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Impossible de récuppérer les éléments de la page " + link.substring(link.length() - 2) + " : " + e);
    }
});
```

I have better results but it's still not perfect :

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-17] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  - Failed to get data from page 12 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 30 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 5 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-27] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 35 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[main] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 22 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 1 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 2 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-21] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 17 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] INFO  service.MagicBazarReader  -  Failed to get data from page 31 : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure  
[...]
[main] INFO  ISmellProfits  - Number of result after HTML parsing : 286
```

So I'm getting a lot more results after `HTML` parsing, but they are not consistent since i have a different number on every run and i'm still getting `SSLHandshakeException`.

I'm getting out of idea so I'm asking if someone know what is causing the exception to be thrown.
I'm new to using *JSOUP* so I still don't know it well.
I think it could be that *JSOUP* can only have on connection at a time an the loop is calling the new one before the first one is closed.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You should close your connection after each end of loop. Maybe your site doesn't allow more than 1 connection per client.

Comment: I just ran your code locally, I could successfully get all 35 pages. Can it be your internet connection that would be unstable? Are you sure the exceptions are thrown by the code you shared? Or can the "here i'm parsing the HTML to return an array of object" section be the culprit?

Comment: @Pilpo Jsoup closes the connection by its own, after the request is done.

Comment: @sp00m which code did you use ? i did some debugging on Jsoup.connect().get() to be sure and it does throw  Method threw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException' exception : Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. But i will try on another internet connection

Comment: @Pulco I ran https://pastebin.com/HBSfNX6V and all went good (Java 11 with Jsoup 1.14.2).

Comment: Edit :  i tried on another connection and i have the same failure

Comment: @sp00m i tried with your code and got   Getting page 1
Got page 1
Getting page 2
Getting page 3
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. The issue seems to be with the internet connection.

Comment: @Pilpo - just FYI re: "You should close your connection after each end of loop". Jsoup manages the connection itself when you call get() or execute(). There's nothing to close. The connect() method just prepares a request, it doesn't actually make any network IO or have anything to leak.

Comment: @Pulco you might want to try rate limiting your requests, if there's a flaky network connection (maybe a proxy along the way), perhaps going slower would help.

Comment: @JonathanHedley i tried this https://pastebin.com/W6JEFHyW by adding Guava Ratelimiter to only have a request per second but it's still failling. Or maybe you were talking about other type of ways to limit my requests.

Comment: So it seems the issue was with my computer in particular, i did a run on my laptop and it worked with no issue. 
I will look if my antivirus software is not blocking my connection.

Comment: You can check if it's due to the number of concurrent threads by limiting them: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool

Comment: **Which 11?** If it was specifically 11.0.1, failure on TLS1.3 connections _after_ the first completes (i.e. resumptions) [could be same as this (also jsoup!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913758/java-11-https-connection-fails-with-ssl-handshakeexception-while-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 1):

[RESOLVED]

So it seems the issue is with the JDK11 and the presence of TLSv1.3 among the protocols enabled by default in the JDK. I tried with JDK 16 and i have no issue anymore.
A link to a post who goes deeper in the explanation : [Java 11 and 12 SSL sockets fail on a handshake_failure error with TLSv1.3 enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601284/java-11-and-12-ssl-sockets-fail-on-a-handshake-failure-error-with-tlsv1-3-enable)