# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure even after disabling SSL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm trying to access AWS API Gateway endpoint using Java's HttpsURLConnection (java version "1.8.0_91").

https://at0yve8x72.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/v1/shorten

But I'm getting "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" even though I have disabled SSL Certificate verification.

In my code below if I comment **HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv)** then everything works fine. But I'm not allowed to comment this in my project as it would impact other modules. I'm not sure why setting DefaultHostnameVerifier is causing handshake failure.

Here is my code,

```
public class ShortTestCls {

      public static void disableCertificateValidation() {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
              new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                  return new X509Certificate[0]; 
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            }};

            // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
            HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
              public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try {
              SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

              sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
              HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
              HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
          }


       public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

            disableCertificateValidation();

             URL url = new URL("https://at0yve8x72.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/v1/shorten?longurl=http://test.com");
             HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
             System.out.println("ResponseCoede ="+conn.getResponseCode());
       }
}
```

Here is the SSL debug logs,

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1455464809 bytes = { 69, 105, 27, 228, 90, 70, 203, 33, 93, 150, 199, 96, 215, 23, 7, 29, 152, 74, 251, 210, 120, 250, 42, 86, 39, 219, 146, 71 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 193
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at ShortTestCls.main(ShortTestCls.java:49)
```

From the above log It appears that AWS API gateway is completely rejecting my clienthello. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

I would be grateful for any advice, which helps me in solving this problem. There are some questions connected with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: but couldn't find any solution there.

Comment: A handshake error has nothing to do with validation of the server certificate so it helps not to disable validation (which is a bad idea anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=at0yve8x72.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com&s=52.84.213.166&latest) the site requires the [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension. Based on your debug output your client does not send this extension.

This might be related to the bug, that JDK 1.8 fails to use SNI in case `setDefaultHostnameVerifier` is used. Thus I recommend to remove this verifier and keep the default verifier. See [Extended server_name (SNI Extension) not sent with jdk1.8.0 but send with jdk1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817934/extended-server-name-sni-extension-not-sent-with-jdk1-8-0-but-send-with-jdk1-7) for more information about this problem.

> But I'm getting "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" even though I have disabled SSL Certificate verification.

A handshake failure is unrelated to validation of the server certificate. Thus disabling validation will not help. Apart from that disabling validation is a bad idea since it weakens the protection offered by SSL to a point where man in the middle attacks are trivial. And it is even not necessary for this site. Disabling hostname verification is similar bad and also not needed for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For production I'll enable certification validation but for development I want to disable it. As you mentioned i'll go ahead with default verifier.

Comment: @user3820681 See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34296145/185565 answer using a custom SSLFactory facade magically allows a custom hostnameverifier. I tested a same code in JDK7 and JDK8 both work, JDK8 fails without a facade factory.