# Java 8 https connection fails on some sites

Tags: java, ssl, https, sslhandshakeexception, sni

I cannot access some of https resources. Please help to make https calls reliable. Examples I put here tested from Firefox browser, to ensure they are works properly.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I also checked website where https connection works and others, that are fail( errors samples here) are seems use same connection encryption: **TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 128 bit keys, TLS 1.2**

I need to collect data from few web services located on different domains and servers. Some of them are set with http and some are with https. I not collect any secured info, and just need to get web page content. So I trust all:

```
public class SSLSetupService {
    /*
     * Turn SSL certificate check off
     */
    public void trustAll(){
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {     
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                    //return new X509Certificate[0];
                    return null;
                } 
                public void checkClientTrusted( 
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    } 
                public void checkServerTrusted( 
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } 
        }; 

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        }

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);       
    }
}
```

To call http/https links I use:

```
httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection();
httpUrlConnection.connect();
```

This works fine for some of resources, but some of them are fail. Here 3 different web sites calls examples. Every call log starts with "GET:". As I see exception is not the same in each case.

```
GET:

Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(20000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1502506115 bytes = { 25, 180, 202, 131, 207, 32, 63, 124, 254, 251, 240, 50, 201, 158, 201, 12, 150, 235, 114, 135, 54, 151, 137, 50, 9, 70, 113, 165 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 209
0000: 01 00 00 CD 03 03 5A 8E   6D 83 19 B4 CA 83 CF 20  ......Z.m...... 
0010: 3F 7C FE FB F0 32 C9 9E   C9 0C 96 EB 72 87 36 97  ?....2......r.6.
0020: 89 32 09 46 71 A5 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  .2.Fq...d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 40 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  @...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00D0: 02                                                 .
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
[Raw write]: length = 214
0000: 16 03 03 00 D1 01 00 00   CD 03 03 5A 8E 6D 83 19  ...........Z.m..
0010: B4 CA 83 CF 20 3F 7C FE   FB F0 32 C9 9E C9 0C 96  .... ?....2.....
0020: EB 72 87 36 97 89 32 09   46 71 A5 00 00 64 C0 24  .r.6..2.Fq...d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 40 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....@..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 04 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 50                                              .P
main, READ: Unknown-3.4 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)


GET:

Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(20000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1502506128 bytes = { 136, 18, 11, 19, 224, 98, 252, 44, 221, 58, 72, 194, 186, 155, 136, 191, 60, 167, 216, 0, 254, 0, 147, 101, 205, 193, 29, 236 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 209
0000: 01 00 00 CD 03 03 5A 8E   6D 90 88 12 0B 13 E0 62  ......Z.m......b
0010: FC 2C DD 3A 48 C2 BA 9B   88 BF 3C A7 D8 00 FE 00  .,.:H.....<.....
0020: 93 65 CD C1 1D EC 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  .e......d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 40 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  @...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00D0: 02                                                 .
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
[Raw write]: length = 214
0000: 16 03 03 00 D1 01 00 00   CD 03 03 5A 8E 6D 90 88  ...........Z.m..
0010: 12 0B 13 E0 62 FC 2C DD   3A 48 C2 BA 9B 88 BF 3C  ....b.,.:H.....<
0020: A7 D8 00 FE 00 93 65 CD   C1 1D EC 00 00 64 C0 24  ......e......d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 40 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....@..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure


javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)


GET:

Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(20000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1502506148 bytes = { 153, 12, 202, 254, 215, 119, 166, 31, 255, 121, 47, 149, 116, 98, 151, 139, 157, 234, 76, 226, 153, 250, 248, 231, 222, 67, 131, 79 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 209
0000: 01 00 00 CD 03 03 5A 8E   6D A4 99 0C CA FE D7 77  ......Z.m......w
0010: A6 1F FF 79 2F 95 74 62   97 8B 9D EA 4C E2 99 FA  ...y/.tb....L...
0020: F8 E7 DE 43 83 4F 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ...C.O..d.$.(.=.
0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
0090: 40 00 0A 00 16 00 14 00   17 00 18 00 19 00 09 00  @...............
00A0: 0A 00 0B 00 0C 00 0D 00   0E 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
00D0: 02                                                 .
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 209
[Raw write]: length = 214
0000: 16 03 03 00 D1 01 00 00   CD 03 03 5A 8E 6D A4 99  ...........Z.m..
0010: 0C CA FE D7 77 A6 1F FF   79 2F 95 74 62 97 8B 9D  ....w...y/.tb...
0020: EA 4C E2 99 FA F8 E7 DE   43 83 4F 00 00 64 C0 24  .L......C.O..d.$
0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 40 00 0A   00 16 00 14 00 17 00 18  .....@..........
00A0: 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00 0B   00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
00D0: 02 03 02 01 02 02                                  ......
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_121]

Keep-Alive-Timer, called close()
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeInternal(true)
Keep-Alive-Timer, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 2
0000: 01 00                                              ..
Keep-Alive-Timer, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
[Raw write]: length = 31
0000: 15 03 03 00 1A 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 02 CB 8C CF  ................
0010: 07 82 ED 46 53 E7 1E 82   48 0D A4 03 59 9F D7     ...FS...H...Y..
Keep-Alive-Timer, called closeSocket(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: Checking each byte of your debug log just confirms the server doesn't want to go further with your client. bytes 15 03 03 = TLS 1.2 ALERT ( https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-5 ), and the bytes 02 28 = fatal alert / handshake_failure ( https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#page-28 ). Typically this happens when you're not enabling the good ciper suites, but you're saying that checking with a browser shows the same cipher suite chosen by the server in each case including the ones which are working with your Java client, and that is disturbing.

Comment: Please test all of your servers against SSL Labs to see if there is any difference in the protocols allowed ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html )

Comment: Got an idea, give me some minutes to check.. Maybe there is anything to enable/force the SNI in your client. Are your requesting FQDNs or IP addresses ?

Comment: Please check update - you can see the link examples

Comment: I tried with SSL Labs ... configs seems they all support TLS 1.2 and cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256. Is it possible that my application JAVA VM not acepts this config for some reason? I not sure is this possible to know from logs I posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to SSL Labs, both sites which aren't working give this interesting result :

> This site works only in browsers with SNI support.

This is what I said in a comment, maybe an SNI issue, which seems to be confirmed.
As we see in your debug log, there is no [server_name extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3) in the ClientHello. We would typically find it after the other extensions that we see in the log (elliptic_curves, ec_point_formats, signature_algorithms)

There's one [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817934/extended-server-name-sni-extension-not-sent-with-jdk1-8-0-but-send-with-jdk1-7) looking a similar, talking about a [Java bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144566) turning off the SNI functionality when using a HostnameVerifier (which is your case). Your JVM version (8u121) is probably guilty, please upgrade as said in the bug information, to 8u141 minimum.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue. Sorry I was busy and not able to check immediately. I am now use Oracle JDK 1.8.0_161 version.

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue when I connect to an API-gateway end point. Can this be because of jdk version of client? My current version is JDK 1.8.0_151.

Comment: @DivyeshKalbhor No, that issue is solved with 8u141.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to allow Perfect Forward Secrecy on the JVM for anything that use HttpsURLConnection ?
i.e.

```
-Dhttps.cipherSuites=[List of ciphersuite supporting PFS]
```

Regards.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: They're already enabled (ECDHE are in the list sent by the browser)

Comment: Could you explain where should I know about [List of ciphersuite supporting PFS] ? I would try then. One more  question is application reliability. Should I maintain such cipherSuites manually later? Will this list be maintained by Java core developers?

Comment: My mistake, it seems effectively already activated on the JVM  (some PFS cyphers are sent in the JVM client hello). I remembered that it was not the case in the first version of JDK 8 that's why I ask you the question.