# javax websocket client ssl connection

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, wss, sslcontext

I have problem with javax.websocket (using Eclipse IDE and Jetty 9 server).
I wrote ClientEnpdoint (with all annotation). This code work fine with "ws://" but i have problem when trying use "wss://".

I'm trying do it with SSLContext, but don't know how i can add SSLContextFactory to my session or socket container.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason.CloseCodes;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

@ClientEndpoint
public class ScriptSocketJavax extends Thread{

    final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ScriptSocketJavax.class);

public int checkWork;
private String type;
private String opertr;
private String client;
private Date date = new Date();
private SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
private Session session;
private URI uri;
WebSocketContainer container;
ClientEndpointConfig endpointConfig;

public ScriptSocketJavax(String opertr, String client, String type) throws Exception{

    this.checkWork = 0;
    this.uri = URI.create("wss://*****"); //ws://****
    this.type = type;
    this.client = client;
    this.opertr = opertr;
    this.container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    this.container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024*1024);
    this.container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024*1024);

    try {

        String STORETYPE = "JKS";
        String KEYSTORE = "C:\\****";
        String STOREPASSWORD = "123456";
        String KEYPASSWORD = "123456";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(STORETYPE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ks);

        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
        sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null );
        sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        this.session = this.container.connectToServer(this, this.uri);  //obj, not class
```

or how i can make all connection trusted?

StackTrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Connect failure
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:261)
at com.stepanov.utils.ScriptSocketJavax.<init>(ScriptSocketJavax.java:80)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 0 null
...
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.onComplete(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:513)
... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
...
... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 29 more
```

Comment: all connections ? It was asked many times, see this question which contains code around TrustManager : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49454296/7748072 .

Answer (score 0):

First of all that URI's certificate should be trusted by your JAVA. To make it trusted by JAVA you need to add the certificate to java key store.

Comment: yes, i did it.
but how i can associate websocket with a certificate?

Comment: It would be better if you could post your full stack trace of the error

Comment: Added stack trace. I think this is due to the fact that I put an ordinary websocket to the argument, to which the certificate is not tied in any way

Comment: could you try this option with java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStore