# How to use SNI with Spring WebSocketClient?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-websocket, stomp, sni

I need to connect to spring websocket server which supports SNI. I am using Spring WebSocket Client which by default does not sends SNI extension as jdk 1.8.0 does not send SNI extension by default.

[Extended server_name (SNI Extension) not sent with jdk1.8.0 but send with jdk1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817934/extended-server-name-sni-extension-not-sent-with-jdk1-8-0-but-send-with-jdk1-7)

The official documentation of java suggests to add SNI Matcher with SSLParameters and set the SSLParameters to SSLSocket before making any HttpsUrlConnection with that SSLSocket.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExtension

Is there any way to set this property with Spring WebSocket Client ?

There are some ClientEndpointCongfig properties that can be set as per given link but I did not find any property which can be used to set SSLSocket or SSLSocketfactory with the Spring websocket client.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html

Here is a sample code for Spring websocket client:

```
List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(1);
        StandardWebSocketClient standardWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        transports.add(new WebSocketTransport( standardWebSocketClient) );
        WebSocketClient transport = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect(URL, sessionHandler);
```

Comment: Hey there, did you find any solution for this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I landed up with this problem as well. In my case I was getting a wrong certificate from EKS cluster because I have multiple hostname configured for a single IP.

So I had to use this [link](http://javabreaks.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-ssl-handshake-with-server-name.html?_sm_au_=iVVZj77NHqPn150Q) as a reference to force SNI information with the request. However did not find a way to do this with spring standadrd wensocket client.

I have used this ([link](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java)) websocket client to resolve this issue. Basically I had to provide socket factory wrapper from above link to the websocket client.

Something like : 
`SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactoryWrapper(sslContext, sslParameters);
webSocket.setSocketFactory(factory);`

Comment: Can you explain further what you did? I have a `WebSocketStompClient` and no way of setting a socket factory? What WebSocket client do you use in Spring for this to work? Please share the detailed code if possible

Comment: I can't figure out what you defined as `sslContext`

Comment: I am not sure I can share the code (legal issue), however you may study this link - https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/08/web-socket-java-client-stomp-spring-server-side.html